# C# print chinese characters with razorPdf

Tags: c#, chinese-locale

I'm trying to print an pdf with chinese characters using RazorPdf.

I've already try to create the font "STSong-Light with the enconding "UniGB-UCS2-H".

http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch09.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196019/Display-Chinese-Characters-in-PDF-created-by-iText

My Code:

```
string fontpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Content\\fonts\\stsong.ttf";
BaseFont baseFT = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
//BaseFont baseFT = BaseFont.CreateFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance and regards.